# Linq Expressions and Aggregate classes

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

How do I build Linq Expressions for aggregate classes? Let me explain with an example of what I am trying to do. Say, I want to find all employees with pay not equal to 50000 and here's the class structure.

```
    Employee e1 = new Employee { Name = "Jane", PDetail = new PayDetail { Salary = 100000 } };
    Employee e2 = new Employee { Name = "Joe", PDetail = new PayDetail { Salary = 50000 } };

    emps.Add(e1);
    emps.Add(e2);

//I started doing it this way and this code DOES NOT compile

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PayDetail));

var where = Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Property(parameter, "Salary"), Expression.Constant(50000));

var pred = Expression.Lambda(where, parameter);

var query = Enumerable.Where(emps, (Func<PayDetail, Boolean>)pred.Compile());
```

**EDIT: Any help with the null issue (as noted in the comments)? Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the correct arguments to the `Enumerable.Where` method. You are passing a list of `Employee` and a method that works on `PayDetail`. You could use

```
var query = Enumerable
    .Where(emps.Select(e => e.PDetail), (Func<PayDetail, Boolean>)pred.Compile());
```

or the shorter version

```
var query = emps.Select(e => e.PDetail)
    .Where((Func<PayDetail, Boolean>)pred.Compile());
```

Which will get you the right `PayDetails` but not the right `Employee`s'. I believe you're really looking for:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee));

var where = Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Property(
    Expression.Property(parameter, "PDetail"), "Salary"), 
        Expression.Constant(50000));

var pred = Expression.Lambda(where, parameter);

var query = emps.Where((Func<Employee, Boolean>)pred.Compile());
```

Comment: But then how do I get the employee details as well for a condition like "Employees with the name of Jane and salary of 100000"?

Comment: @DotnetDude check out my changes.

Comment: Wow, that works! I looked around a lot online before I posted this. Can you point me to an online Linq resource that goes in depth on Expression trees and advanced stuff? I am not exactly sure how you got this working. Thanks

Comment: Also, what if I had a List<PayDetail> instead of a PDetail as a part of Employee?

Comment: @DotnetDude actually I just played around with what you had already done. Sometimes it helps just getting another eye on the problem. Doing the List<PayDetail> looks hard, will work on it later when I have time. It looks like you'd need to grab the Exression of the `Enumerable.Any`.

Comment: @Yuriy - The code throws a null exception if one of the employee does not have the PDetail or if the PDetail = null in the initialization.